# Kendo UI File Structure : Proper use of view model, datasource, data binding

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI framework for Front End development. Can anyone help as how to arrange file structure when it comes to complex project?

Comment: Follow the Telerik demos

Comment: Suggest me if you know best Kendo Project Structure. I can see Telerik Demos.

Comment: are you wanting to use Templates?

Comment: Templates are the main constructs in Kendo UI. So I do use them necessarily. Excellent and best practice of  structuring and reusing functionalities of Kendo UI is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I find supportive resource for Project Structure in Kendo UI [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/load-remote).

If anyone knows any better way of project structuring in Kendo, I would appreciate that.